# Android opencv photo capture

Tags: android, opencv, camera, android-camera

I am new to the android. Createing image capturing application using opencv in Android. So I downloaded the opencv 2.4.2 sdk and used the sample **"OpenCV Sample - face-detection"**. Now the camera open and detect well. Now I am going implement photo capturing with this existing face detection. How can I add capture button on opencv camera. Can anyone help me to do this.

Thanks,
Karthi

Comment: I am facing the same problem.Have you solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV native camera (aka VideoCapture class) doesn't support photo taking mode. Look at the Tutorial 1 sample that uses Android Java camera and read about it at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Comment: Thanks. It helps to proceeding next step.